# LibMan without internet prevents build. Is there a local fallback option?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an aspnet core project (dotnet core 2.2). It uses the `Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build (1.0.172)` package. If the network is down, the build fails with a bunch of similar errors:

> Error LIB002  The "toastr.js@2.1.4" library could not be resolved by the "cdnjs" provider C.Web.App   C:\Users\bburns\code\C.WEB.APP\libman.json  1

`libman.json` looks like

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "defaultProvider": "cdnjs",
  "libraries": [
    {
      "library": "jquery@3.3.1",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/jquery"
    },

    ...
```

Is there a way to specify an offline fallback when `cdnjs` is unavailable?

Comment: use a local NPM cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the libs in a local or shared location and reference that in your projects, as in this example of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-3.0#manually-configure-libman-manifest-file-entries):

```
{
  "provider": "filesystem",
  "library": "C:\\temp\\lodash\\",
  "files": [
    "lodash.js",
    "lodash.min.js"
  ],
```

Where library may be a relative path as well.

The drawback is that updates are not detected from the project, so you'll have to think of a strategy on how to keep the libraries up-to-date.

Comment: If I copy them locally, does that mean I own the libs?